# Incorrect epoch date in node.js using thrift

Tags: node.js, integer, thrift, epoch

I seem to be getting a different epoch date value in node.js for a thrift object than what is stored in the mongo database and returned by the service

Thrift definition file (thrift v0.9.0), I have

```
struct Profile {
    ...
    4: i64 createDate,
    5: i64 lastUpdateDate
```

Mongo record

```
"createdTimestamp" : NumberLong("1366334385361"),
"lastUpdatedTimestamp" : NumberLong("1366334385361")
```

Node reports

```
createDate: 534785233,
lastUpdateDate: 534785233
```

The generated node thrift client seems to have I64 referenced.

```
if (this.createDate !== null && this.createDate !== undefined) {
    output.writeFieldBegin('createDate', Thrift.Type.I64, 14);
    output.writeI64(this.createDate);
    output.writeFieldEnd();
}
```

I appreciate any insight that comes along.

Thanks

Comment: Additional data points: service is written in Java. The Java service source for the Profile being returned has `private long createdTimestamp;` `private long lastUpdatedTimestamp;`

Comment: Possibly related to a [thrift node issue - THRIFT-1841](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1841) ?

Answer (score 1):

Binary representation for given numbers are :

```
1366334385361  ->  10011111000011111111000000010110011010001
534785233      ->  00000000000011111111000000010110011010001
```

i.e. if you take lower 32 bits of 1366334385361, you get 534785233. So somewhere in your program or package you are using, it is getting converted/truncated into 32 bit integer e.g. int(1366334385361)

Comment: Thanks for confirming a hunch that the number was a truncated 32 bit int. The provider of the java thrift service has confirmed that their retrieval of the 64bit NumberLong in mongo is properly being outputted  in the thrift service response. I'll re-confirm again to make sure.   The thrift definition file identifies it as I64 and the node thrift client is said to have the 64bit support rolled in. I'm trying to help rule it out as a thrift bug either on the node or the java side.